# Fast method to change aspx extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I use this way to rewite requested URL that have `abc` extension to `aspx` extension(found in SO):

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  String fullOrigionalpath = Request.Url.ToString();
  String[] sElements = fullOrigionalpath.Split('/');
  String[] sFilePath = sElements[sElements.Length - 1].Split('.');
  if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains(".abc") )
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFilePath[0].Trim()))
         Context.RewritePath(sFilePath[0] + ".aspx");
}
```

but it seems this way is too slow. Can you say me How can I do this in `web.config` or other fast way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Path.ChangeExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx). *Don't Invent the wheel*.

```
string aspxPath = Path.ChangeExtension(fullOrigionalpath, "aspx");
```

Comment: As a note to anyone that lands on here looking to remove an extension from a path, `String.Empty` will remove the extension and keep the dot, and `null` will remove both the extension itself and the dot.